# DevExpress MVC GridView callbacks frozen after first call back

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, mvcgrid

I am using DevExpress MVC GridView in my project, I have faced a funny problem lets say during implementation of the GridView. The GridView Works fine if do not use any other script tags in my view but when i add some scripts to my view the grid view looks pretty fine but when i click on a link like New, Edit or any of them, the call backs stop working and the loading panel showed infinitely. any help would be appreciated.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DevLayout.cshtml";
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>GIZ/WSIP-Operation Plan</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/css/datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/css/bootstrap.css">
<link href="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/css/datepicker.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet'
    type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/ css? family= Droid+Serif :400,700,400  
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700'  
    type='text/css'>
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page-top" class="index">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon- bar"></span><span
                    class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Operation Plan</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top"></a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Create</a> </li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Edit</a> </li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Activities Chart</a> </li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Report</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in">
                Welcome To Our Studio!</div>
            <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Services Section -->
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">
                    Create</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">
                    Create new Intervention Area and Activities Here.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/       jquery/ 1.7/jquery.js">      </script>
 </head>

  <body>

  <div class="container">

       <!-------->
  <div id="content">
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
<li onClick="window.location='http://localhost:53785/firstcmoutputs    /Create#services'"><a href="http://localhost:53785/firstcmoutputs/Create#services"     data-toggle="tab">Output</a></li>
<li onClick="window.location='http://localhost:53785/firstcmActivities    /Create#services'"><a href="http://localhost:53785/firstcmActivities/Create#services"     data-toggle="tab">Activities</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="Output">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.Partial("_OutputsCreateOrEdit")

}
```

```
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>





</div> <!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
</section>
<!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
<section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
@Html.Action("GridViewPartial")

</section>
<!-- About Section -->
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">
                    About</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; GIZ-WSIP 2014</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing    /1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/contact_me.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/agency.js"></script>
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#PlanningFrom").datepicker();
    $("#PlanningTo").datepicker();
    $("#DateOfPlanning").datepicker();

});
 </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case different js files are conflicting with each other.

Just Try using `$.noConflict()` to avoid conflicts between jquery's files :-

Follow this link :

**http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/**

Comment: Would you please give me some more tips how to do this? Because i have lots of <script> tags in my view i was unable to figure out how to do this?

Comment: @NaserDostdar...you can visit link given in anser..it will explain you completely...

Comment: I have to say that i have removed all conflicting Jquery scripts means i changed all to one Jquery file but even that still same error any idea?

Comment: @NaserDostdar...plz post some code..so that we can get your problem easily..thankzz...